# How can I simulate 512GB Nand Flash using NandSim？

Tags: linux-device-driver

I need to mount the Yaffs file system on my Ubuntu system to test its memory overhead, because the Yaffs file system can only mount to Nand Flash, so I need to simulate a 512GB or 1TB NAND Flash.

When I used NandSim to do this, I found that it only simulates up to 64GB of NAND Flash, which is too small for my needs.

```
$sudo modprobe nandsim first_id_byte=0xec second_id_byte=0xd3 third_id_byte=0x51 fourth_id_byte=0x15
$sudo modprobe mtdblock
$sudo mkdir -p  /media/nand
$sudo mount -t yaffs /dev/mtdblock0 /media/nand
```

I also tried using mtdram and block2mtd, but they emulated NOR flash and I couldn't mount yaffs on it.

So I was wondering if there was a way or tool that could emulate a 512GB or 1TB nandFlash, and I could mount the Yaffs file system to it.

ps：I have enough RAM.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use the `cache_file` module parameter to simulate devices that are larger than the available memory.

Comment: Have you tried using the `overridesize` module parameter? `overridesize:Specifies the NAND Flash size overriding the ID bytes. The size is specified in erase blocks and as the exponent of a power of two e.g. 5 means a size of 32 erase blocks (uint)`

Comment: @lanAbbott Thanks, I just tried this method with the command  `sudo modprobe nandsim first_id_byte=0xec second_id_byte=0xd3 third_id_byte=0x51 fourth_id_byte=0x15 overridesize=20` to emulate a 128GB Nand Flash，but I got the message `[nandsim] error: Too many erase blocks for wear reporting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After everyone's efforts, we found a way to simulate more than 64GB devices with nandsim.The key point is the `overridesize`module paremeter.But you still need modify the source code which in nandsim.c.

[This is a specific method](https://blog.cyyself.name/nandsim-larger-than-64g/)